# When we create a new a process, where in the linux kernel is its priority assigned?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using Linux 4.19.2
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/ident/

I figured out the structure called *task_struct* which contains all the information in the Process Control Block. When we create a new process, the *fork()* function is called, which in turn, calls functions like *_do_fork()* and *copy_process()* to provide values for the fields in *task_struct*.

However, I couldn't find out where is the priority of a new process. The field name used for priority in the task_struct structure is *prio*. Where does it get its value from, when a process is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried figuring it out from this link https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/ident/

This provides a Linux kernels cross-referenced, that I can read. I figured out that to fork a new process, the function [_do_fork()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L2135) calls [copy_process()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L1628) which in turn calls a function called [sched_fork()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L1628).

This is where the priority of the process is initialised using the function [normal_prio()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L772).